# How to dynamically change the height of datatable with respect to the view port when the scrolling is enabled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, slimscroll

I am trying to enable the scroll option of `datatable` and applying `slimScroll` to it to make the scroll bar sleek looking. So far I am getting what I wanted to do.

Soon I realized, 'What if user re-sizes the window?'. Since the settings of both datatable and slimScroll are configured with fixed value, the height of data-table wont adjust as per viewport size.

I tried to fix this issue with the help of `$(window).resize()` event, but its not working. I am not that good at javaScript programming. I might have done something wrong or there must be some other way. This is the code I have written so far.

```
   //Data table
   var table = $('#material-content').DataTable({
       'paging'    : false,
       'info'      : false,
       'order'     : [[1, 'desc']],
       "scrollY"   : $(window).height()*0.46    // want to have 46% of viewport
   });

   // scrolling

   var scroller =  $('.dataTables_scrollBody').slimScroll({
           "height": $(window).height()*0.46
       });


   $(window).resize(function () {
       var tableSettings    = table.fnSettings(); // ERROR says: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
       var scrollerSettings = scroller.fnSettings();

       tableSettings.scrollY = $(window).height()*0.46;
       scrollerSettings.height = $(window).height()*0.46;

       tableSettings.fnDraw();
       scrollerSettings.fnDraw();
   });
```

Comment: what you are getting as result as of now??

Comment: @GuruprasadRao oh yeah, forgot to mention that. Inside the $(window).resize() method, it displays an error (I have edited in my question). (Inspected from browser console)

Comment: that means `fnSettings` is not being identified as a function!! either that function is not there or initialization has not been done properly..